# Shortcut for if statements (Too many posts to check if isset)

Tags: php

I have a BIG amount of posts to check, if they are set.

```
        if 
        (
            isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['type']) && isset($_POST['typeid']) && isset($_POST['name']) 
            && isset($_POST['level']) && isset($_POST['thumbnail']) && isset($_POST['def']) && isset($_POST['resist']) 
            && isset($_POST['health']) && isset($_POST['mana']) && isset($_POST['stamia']) && isset($_POST['str']) 
            && isset($_POST['dex']) && isset($_POST['rec']) && isset($_POST['int']) && isset($_POST['wis']) && isset($_POST['luc']) 
            && isset($_POST['information']) && isset($_POST['gold']) && isset($_POST['tradeable']) && isset($_POST['faction'])
            && isset($_POST['category'])
        )
        {
```

I tried doing this:

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
```

But then I forgot to fill some fields, and it didn't throw any error and processed.

**My question:**

How can I check if all of these posts were set without a mess? any shorter ways to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$requiredFields = array('id', 'type', ...);
if (array_diff_key(array_flip($requiredFields), $_POST)) {
    die('Not all fields were posted');
}
if (count(array_filter($_POST)) != count($_POST)) {
    die('Some fields were empty');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need that. Form values are set by default, save for checkboxes.
So, most of time you don't need this checking at all.

#### Moreover, it would be wrong to check values this way.

PHP [when properly configured] is good enough with catching absent fields. It will tell you what field you missed or misspelled in the form. While your current approach won't let you know which particular field is wrong.

So, instead of writing useless code - just let PHP handle the case.

It you want to check if some values consists of empty strings (or spaces) - that's another matter. You can use some sort of loop for this. Like

```
if (count(array_filter($_POST,'trim')) != count($_POST))
```

Comment: Generally yes, except that you still need to assure all fields you expect are actually posted before you try to work with them if you want to avoid possible errors.

Comment: I don't want to avoid possible errors. Such errors like on absent file or a POST field **are** for this purpose, to alarm an integrity violation

Answer (score 0):

Create an array to keep all your fields:

```
$fields = array('id', 'type', 'typeid');
```

And loop through this array:

```
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (! isset($_POST[$field])) {
        // here you have some missed data
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use something like this:

put all your post keys in an array and in a for statement check all your keys are set:

```
function checkPost()
{
for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($array) ; $i++)
{
   if (!isset($_POST[$array[$i]])
     return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use a foreach loop as follows. Test using the count function. You will need to test for cross site scripting and sql injection too so remember to validate the post values

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value ) {
    if($value == '') {
       $errors[] = 1; //adds a value to the errors array if value is not populated
    }
}

//check if the errors array is populated.
if( count($errors) > 0 ) {
    // don't submit
} else {
    //submit
}
```